# View only the methods in a partial class file in solution explorer Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015 solution explorer when I expand a node that is a file for a partial class it lists all the methods, fields & parameters for the complete class. This list in the drop down when editing the file is also for the complete class.

Is it possible to configure VS2015 to show only the methods/parameters in the file being examined / edited?

Searching this problem only discovers a method for showing all files for a partial class as a heirarchy in solution explorer.

There are a core set of methods in one file and each of the other files are in different subfolders each file having a closely related group of  methods.

Comment: No, but you can create "inner" private classes for every partial file

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help, Could you explain further please? Wouldn't private classes hide the method functions? (these need to be accessible from other classes).